# Doctrine2 default timestamp wtih "0000-00-00 00:00:00" format?

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, doctrine-orm, timestamp

I am using Doctrine2 ORM. I have an `order` table.

```
Name                | Type       | Attributes                  | Null | Default
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
order_id            | int        |                             | No   | None
date_created        | timestamp  |                             | No   | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
date_edited         | timestamp  | on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP | No   | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
date_sent           | timestamp  |                             | No   | 0000-00-00 00:00:00
date_cancelled      | timestamp  |                             | No   | 0000-00-00 00:00:00
requested_ship_date | timestamp  |                             | No   | 0000-00-00 00:00:00
```

I have added the [Timestampable](https://github.com/Atlantic18/DoctrineExtensions) Doctrine Extension to use for the `date_created` and `date_edited` fields like so:

```php
/**
 * @var \DateTime 
 *
 * @Gedmo\Timestampable(on="create")
 * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
 */
private $date_created;

/**
 * @var \DateTime 
 *
 * @Gedmo\Timestampable(on="update")
 * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
 */
private $date_edited;
```

However, I'm not sure what to do for `date_sent` and `date_cancelled`. I want them both to default to `0000-00-00 00:00:00` instead of the current time. I saw [this workaround](http://www.franzdeleon.me/2013/11/tip-how-to-add-timestamp-with.html) for using timestamps in Doctrine2 without a plugin, but I don't want the default to be the current timestamp for these. The reason being, users can 'save' an order but not 'send' it to someone. Also, I obviously don't want the `date_cancelled` to be the current timestamp.

**Note:** I don't want to store nulls in the database, so please don't suggest that.

Thanks in advance.

## Update

I currently have this for the three remaining fields in my Order entity.

```php
/**
 * @var \DateTime 
 *
 * @ORM\Column(type="datetime", options={"default":"0000-00-00 00:00:00"})
 * @ORM\Version
 */
private $date_sent;

/**
 * @var \DateTime 
 *
 * @ORM\Column(type="datetime", options={"default":"0000-00-00 00:00:00"})
 * @ORM\Version
 */
private $date_cancelled;

/**
 * @var \DateTime 
 *
 * @ORM\Column(type="datetime", options={"default":"0000-00-00 00:00:00"})
 * @ORM\Version
 */
private $requested_ship_date;
```

For some reason, when I try to update the `requested_ship_date` field, it ends up being "0000-00-00 00:00:00". I leave the `date_sent` and `date_cancelled` fields null and they update to **my local time, not UTC time**. However, the `date_created` and `date_edited` fields will be updated to the current time in UTC time (how I want it).

Basically, when I'm saving an order it looks like the first row, but I want it to look like the second row (assuming the user requested a ship date of 2015-06-08).

```
order_id | date_created        | date_edited         | date_sent           | date_cancelled      | requested_ship_date
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1        | 2015-06-05 12:00:00 | 2015-06-05 12:00:00 | 2015-06-05 07:00:00 | 2015-06-05 07:00:00 | 0000-00-00 00:00:00  
1        | 2015-06-05 12:00:00 | 2015-06-05 12:00:00 | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 | 2015-06-08 00:00:00
```

I have set the timezone in my index.php file like so `date_default_timezone_set('Zulu');`. I don't reset the timezone anywhere else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I found a crazy workaround for this, but I honestly couldn't find a better solution. So, for anyone else stuck in the same mess I am, you're welcome lol.

First, the rules:

- `date_created` = updated only on creation
- `date_edited` = updated on every update
- `date_sent` = updated when user clicks "submit" instead of "save"
- `date_cancelled` = updated when user decides to cancel the order
- `requested_ship_date` = required when creating a new order, this is the date the customer wants the order to be shipped by.

Some code from my Order entity.

```
/**
 * @var \DateTime 
 *
 * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
 * @Gedmo\Timestampable(on="create")
 */
private $date_created;

/**
 * @var \DateTime 
 *
 * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
 * @Gedmo\Timestampable(on="update")
 */
private $date_edited;

/**
 * @var \DateTime 
 *
 * @ORM\Column(type="datetime", options={"default":"0000-00-00 00:00:00"})
 */
private $date_sent;

/**
 * @var \DateTime 
 *
 * @ORM\Column(type="datetime", options={"default":"0000-00-00 00:00:00"})
 */
private $date_cancelled;

/**
 * @var \DateTime 
 *
 * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
 * @Gedmo\Timestampable(on="change", field="requested_ship_date")
 */
private $requested_ship_date;


/*
 * Constructor
 */
public function __construct()
{
    if (!$this->date_sent) $this->date_sent = new DateTime("0000-00-00 00:00:00", new DateTimeZone("Zulu"));
    if (!$this->date_cancelled) $this->date_cancelled = new DateTime("0000-00-00 00:00:00", new DateTimeZone("Zulu"));
}

/**
 * Updates time sent 
 *
 * @return Order
 */
public function send()
{
    $this->date_sent = new DateTime("now");

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Updates time cancelled
 *
 * @return Order
 */
public function cancel()
{
    $this->date_cancelled = new DateTime("now");

    return $this;
}
```

Explanation:

I did not change anything of how I set up my database columns in my order table. I tried using the `@Gedmo\Timestampable` plugin for my `date_sent` and `date_cancelled` fields, but couldn't get it to work. I noticed that the timezones were off, for some weird reason, so I manually set them in the constructor. It is important to not automatically set it, or you will override values previously set. For some reason unknown to me, I couldn't get the `requested_ship_date` field working without using the `@Gedmo\Timestampable` plugin. If I took it out, every set up I tried to use with Doctrines `type="datetime"` would just result in the column equaling `0000-00-00 00:00:00`.

If anybody has any questions, let me know. I had to basically poke at things for awhile until I figured it out. The `date_sent` and `date_cancelled` fields worked correctly, and were in the right timezone when I updated them.